# Print message if Semaphore blocks for too long, but don't unblock caller when message is printed

Tags: go, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

I have the following code in Go using the [semaphore](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore) library just as an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "time"
    "golang.org/x/sync/semaphore"
)

// This protects the lockedVar variable
var lock *semaphore.Weighted
// Only one go routine should be able to access this at once
var lockedVar string

func acquireLock() {
    err := lock.Acquire(context.TODO(), 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func releaseLock() {
    lock.Release(1)
}

func useLockedVar() {
    acquireLock()
    fmt.Printf("lockedVar used: %s\n", lockedVar)
    releaseLock()
}

func causeDeadLock() {
    acquireLock()

    // calling this from a function that's already
    // locked the lockedVar should cause a deadlock.
    useLockedVar()

    releaseLock()
}

func main() {
    lock = semaphore.NewWeighted(1)
    lockedVar = "this is the locked var"

    // this is only on a separate goroutine so that the standard
    // go "deadlock" message doesn't print out.
    go causeDeadLock()

    // Keep the primary goroutine active.
    for true {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the `acquireLock()` function call to print a message after a timeout indicating that there is a potential deadlock but without unblocking the call? I would want the deadlock to persist, but a log message to be written in the event that a timeout is reached. So a TryAcquire isn't exactly what I want.

An example of what I want in psuedo code:

```golang
afterFiveSeconds := func() {
    fmt.Printf("there is a potential deadlock\n")
}
lock.Acquire(context.TODO(), 1, afterFiveSeconds)
```

The `lock.Acquire` call in this example would call the `afterFiveSeconds` callback if the `Acquire` call blocked for more than 5 seconds, but it would not unblock the caller. It would continue to block.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to my problem.

```golang
func acquireLock() {
    timeoutChan := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(5)):
            fmt.Printf("potential deadlock while acquiring semaphore\n")
        case <-timeoutChan:
            break
        }
    }()

    err := lock.Acquire(context.TODO(), 1)
    close(timeoutChan)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```